# O código abaixo não está rodando. Somente quando eu retiro as variáveis Largura e Altura de dentro das funções

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

Será que é possível alguém responder essa minha pergunta? Deve ser coisa simples, mas tá me quebrando a cabeça.
O código abaixo não está rodando. Somente quando eu retiro as variáveis Largura e Altura de dentro das funções

```js
function mostrarAreaAlert() {
  var largura = prompt("Digite a largura");
  largura = parseFloat(largura);

  var altura = prompt("Digite a altura");
  altura = parseFloat(altura);

  var area = calcularArea(largura, altura);

  alert('A area total é: ' + area);
}

function mostrarAreaOutput() {
  var largura = prompt("Digite a largura");
  largura = parseFloat(largura);

  var altura = prompt("Digite a altura");
  altura = parseFloat(altura);

  var area = calcularArea(largura, altura);

  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'A area total é: ' + area;
}

function calcularArea(l, a) {
  return l * a;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <button onclick="mostrarAreaAlert(largura, altura)">Mostrar Área em Alert</button>

  <button onclick="mostrarAreaOutput(largura, altura)">Mostrar Área no Output</button>

  <div id="output"></div>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Pelo que eu entendi, não é necessário passar as duas variáveis dentro das funções pois logo elas serão inicializadas quando forem respondidas as perguntas. Dei uma modificada no seu código para ele fique mais reaproveitável. Espero ter ajudado.

```
<button onclick="mostrarAreaAlert()">Mostrar Área em Alert</button>
<button onclick="mostrarAreaOutput()">Mostrar Área no Output</button>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function question() {
        var res = [];

        let largura = prompt("Digite a largura");
        res[0] = parseFloat(largura);

        let altura = prompt("Digite a altura");
        res[1] = parseFloat(altura);

        return res;
    }

    function mostrarAreaAlert() {
        let res = question();

        let area = calcularArea(res[0], res[1]);
        alert('A area total é: ' + area);
    }

    function mostrarAreaOutput() {
        let res = question();

        let area = calcularArea(res[0], res[1]);
        document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'A area total é: ' + area;
    }

    function calcularArea(l, a) {
        return l * a;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Perfeito Fernando, esta sua resposta foi muito útil também. Nosso amigo @Asleep deu um comentário acima, onde respondeu justamente a dúvida que eu tinha, do porque meu código não rodar. Ele informou que era só retirar largura e altura de dentro do onclickmouse dos buttons, e realmente resolveu. De toda forma, muito obrigado pelo tempo que você dedicou em responder minha dúvida, pois foi tanto útil quanto a outra, aprendi outra forma de realizar com seu comentário. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

solução 1

```
var area = largura * altura
```

Depois metes o valor a ser apresentado onde queres.

---

solução 2

O que fizeste nesta função a seguir funcionava se fosse largura e altura, não tens nada iniciado com l e a.

```
function calcularArea(l, a){
        return l * a;
    }
```

Entendes?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela disposição em me atender, mas eu ainda não entendi. Você poderia adequar meu código conforme explicado acima? Com base nisso, entenderia o que devo fazer para que o prompt acione apenas ao clicar nos buttons. Entende? Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: @LucasRodrigues, se não compreendeu a resposta porque a marcou como aceita encerrando sua questão? [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Comment: Para resolver o teu problema, de acordo com o teu codigo, basta alterares o seguinte nele: Nos buttons, quando chamas pelo mostrarareaalert(  ), não precisas da largura e altura lá dentro, deixa os ( ) vazios nos dois e diz-me se funcionou só assim.

Comment: @AugustoVasques
Desculpe, ainda estou aprendendo a mexer aqui. Foi falha minha, obrigado pela orientação.

Comment: @Asleep, perfeito. Funcionou de acordo com sua sugestão. Muito obrigado meu amigo!!!!!